# Passing UIPopover created by UISplitView

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

The new standard Storyboard design for `UISplitView` applications are two navigation controllers in a split view. So I have my iPad in portrait mode and push the master view and I push the `detailView` too (at the same time).

What is the right way to pass over the popover view which is created by the `UISplitView` delegate methods?

I think the easiest way would be to invoke a new `UISplitView` delegate call in the new `detailView` controller. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The only way to do it so far, for me. Make a delegate and pass over the `UINavigationItem`.